# Lucene QueryParser: must contain either one or the other among other MUST clauses

Tags: lucene, query-parser

How can QueryParser from Apache Lucene be used to have a query that either contains term A or term B (or both, but at least one of them). **EDIT: Also, it contains other MUST clauses, e.g., it must contain C and it must contain either A or B.**

Is this then correct?

```
+(A OR B) +C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply: `A OR B` (or just `A B`)

This will generate two `BooleanClause`s with `Occur.SHOULD`. In this case, at least one clause has to match for the whole `BooleanQuery` to match:

```lava
/** Use this operator for clauses that <i>should</i> appear in the 
 * matching documents. For a BooleanQuery with no <code>MUST</code> 
 * clauses one or more <code>SHOULD</code> clauses must match a document 
 * for the BooleanQuery to match.
 * @see BooleanQuery#setMinimumNumberShouldMatch
 */
SHOULD   { @Override public String toString() { return "";  } },
```

---

Answer to the updated question:

`(A OR B) AND C` should do what you want.

I'm not really sure about `+(A OR B) +C` since it looks like it should work but you stated that `+(A OR B)` doesn't work like you expect it to in your original question.

To make sure, you can take a look at what `QueryParser` generates. You'd need this kind of query structure:

- `BooleanQuery`

  - Must: `BooleanQuery`

    - Should: `TermQuery`: *A*
    - Should: `TermQuery`: *B*
  - Must: `TermQuery`: *C*

Comment: Oh okay, that is much simplier than I tought.. Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: I updated the question a bit, because I forgot to mention that my query also contains other MUST clauses..

Comment: thanks for your answer. Just wanted to mention that I compared the output of what you suggested (A OR B) AND C and "my" version +(A OR B) +C and it is the same. So both variants do work (I just had some other error, which irritated me).